# Yii url manager create URL, which Yii can't understand

Tags: php, url, yii, routes

I have a Yii project, where I want to have URLs like this:

```
http://module.project.tld/controler/action?param1=value1&param2=value2
```

My system understands these, and as a programer, I like it better, then the one is generated (some lines below)

I have multiple modules btw...

So when I use something like this in the controller:

```
$this->createUrl('controler/action', array('param1' => 'value1'));
```

then it becomes: */controler/action/param1/value1*

I know this is the "pretty URL" what people using in public systems to create user friendly URLs, but my system can not understand it, and personally I don't like it, so here is my question:

How could I force Yii's URL generator, to create the format, what I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set [`CUrlManager::appendParams`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUrlManager#appendParams-detail) to false in your `config/main.php`.

```
    'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'appendParams'=>false,
        ...
```

Comment: Thank you, I don't know how could I miss this option. I read about the problem everywhere -.-

Comment: It wasn't easy to find. Had to look at the CUrlManager source code.